# Want to use one tag with different values according to the scenario in cucumber

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber

we have a cleanup hook in our automation framework which tagged from the cucumber feature file

E.g

@cc_task_clean_up_hook_enrol_A
 Scenario: Person can enrol_A
    When I select the context menu
    Then I am able to enroll the patient into 'enrol_A'

the implementation of the hook (@cc_task_clean_up_hook) is

```
@After(value = "@toc_task_clean_up_hook_enrol_A", order = HookOrder.CLEAN_UP_APP_AFTER)
public void cleanUpTOC() {
    this.patientContextPage.selectedContextMenuItem("Pathway");
    this.pathWayPage.selectReferences("Enroll in Pathway");
    this.pathWayPage.deactivateEnrollment("enrol_A", "Withdrawn");
}
```

So exactly the same way we need an another scenario like

Scenario: Person can enroll_B
    When I select the context menu
    Then I am able to enroll the patient into 'enrollB'

So we can implement another hook as follows, the difference is the parameter type "enrollB"

```
@After(value = "@toc_task_clean_up_hook_enrollB", order = HookOrder.CLEAN_UP_APP_AFTER)
public void cleanUpTOC() {
    this.patientContextPage.selectedContextMenuItem("Pathway");
    this.pathWayPage.selectReferences("Enroll in Pathway");
    this.pathWayPage.deactivateEnrollment("enrol_B", "Withdrawn");
}
```

So is it possible to consolidate these two methods and write only one generic clean up hook, based on the passed parameter? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the scenario object to the arguments passed to the after hook. The framework will inject the currently executing scenario to the method.

```
public void afterMethod(Scenario scenario){}
```

1. You can use the `getSourceTagNames()` method of the `Scenario` object which will return you the collection of tags for the current executing scenario. From this collection you can determine if you have the tag ending with 'enroll_A' or 'enroll_B'.
2. Or you can use the `getName()` method which returns the description of the current scenario. So you will get either 'Person can enroll_A' or 'P..... enroll_B'. Just need to parse again.
3. You can modify the `Then step` to pass the enroll type to step definition. Store this in a variable. Use this variable in your after hook. But this will require the after hook to be in the same class.

Also you will need to change the `value parameter of After` hook to - `{"@toc_task_clean_up_hook_enrollA,@toc_task_clean_up_hook_enrollB"}`.

One observation that these two seem to have the same steps, if so then have you considered ScenarioOutline instead.